# Firebase Web Push: как добавить свой звук?

Tags: php, firebase, push-уведомления, fcm

Я только начинаю знакомится с firebase. Когда я сделал приложение, то я свою звуки разместил в папке /res/raw и тогда push приходил с моим звуком.

Теперь мне надо сделать уведомления в браузере. Как сделать там свой звук?

И еще вопрос: можно ли проиграть звук, когда пользователь на сайте?

Comment: конкретный звук на оповещения вы никак не сделаете. А в целом, если человек находится в браузере (открыта вкладка сайта) и в это время приходит уведомление, то можете обработать это событие и проиграть какой-то звук.

Comment: у меня подключено web push от сайта https://www.duolingo.com/. и когда они приходят - у них свой звук. по поводу того, когда открыта вкладка - да, это я сделал

Comment: а как добавить стандартный?